# Spoof IP address for HTTP web request?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a web service on a server in my company that we have restricted access to from all but one other server on our network.

I do however need to make calls to this from another machine. Is there a way I can spoof the other servers IP address in order to send an http request to the web service? I only need to send it info I don't need any returned data. It's for logging hits from another server on our main server.

I am using this

```
IPEndPoint endpointAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), 80);
using (Socket socket = new Socket(endpointAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    socket.SendTimeout = 500;
    socket.Connect(endpointAddress);
    socket.Send(byteGetString, byteGetString.Length, 0);
}
```

but get an exception

> A connection attempt failed because
>   the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond
>   23.202.147.163:80

Comment: If you don't care about the returned data they yes, it's definitely possible.  I'm not sure exactly how, however.  Maybe someone else can tell you.  Probably it involves writing raw TCP/IP packets.

Comment: I'm far from being a web expert but how would you expect to make a TCP connection with the server if you're spoofing your IP.  How would they even get back to you to even finish the handshake?

Comment: I dont need to finish it i just need to send it a packet with fake http data. The response data is unimportant.

Comment: It sounds like you need to talk to network admin and get them to add the second ip address.

Comment: @eat: Well you can't use TCP for this then AFAIK.  There's no sense in trying to send data if you can't establish a connection with the server, and that involves the initial handshake and all other communication.  You can send packets all you like but the server will probably just drop them.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado - You can still handshake with the server even if you can't get the response packet(s) from it.  You just send your SYN packet, wait a brief while, and then follow with an ACK packet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to *establish* a TCP connection with a server without being able to receive and process some reply packets from that server. HTTP is built upon TCP, and TCP starts communications with a "3-way handshake" that lets the client and server communicate.

The start of an HTTP request is not a single packet.

Comment: I believe you may be oversimplifying.  It may still be possible to handshake with the server even if you can't get the packets that it sends.  You just need to make the correct assumptions about what packets the server thinks you received and respond accordingly.  Given that the SYN/ACK packets in TCP just use increasing sequence numbers, this may be possible.

Comment: @aroth: It's been a long time since [TCP sequence number prediction attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_sequence_prediction_attack) were widely possible. Maybe still possible in some old, broken implementations.

Comment: Exactly. -1. This was abused on teh web, so it does not work anymore. naturally many admins dont update their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a proxy to bounce your requests from an IP address that has access.